# Как сделать прозрачность относительно другого элемента через css?

Tags: css

Всем привет. Есть такой блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Синяя линия реализована следующим образом:

```
.first-page .frame {   
    width: 80%;
    border: 10px solid rgb(19,74,136);
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    height: 175px;
    left: 70px;
    z-index: -1;                
}
```

Сделал, чтобы текст был выше синей линии с помощью `z-index`, но получается такая картина: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы под текстом не было синей линии, но была картинка? `background-color: transparent` на текст не сработал (и не должен был)

Comment: svg  в помощь, ибо не получится так порезать

Comment: рамку нарисовать на задней картинке не вариант?)

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос код, имеющий к нему отношение. Для начала, пожалуйста, прочитайте эту статью: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @programmer403 нет, высота блока динамичная, картинка через `background-size: cover` растягивается :( уже думал над этим, но это невозможно в данной ситуации

Comment: @nicael Вы уверены, что то, что я написал, не является достаточным для понимания задачи?

Comment: Я, например, не понял, почему в первом случае текст обрезает линию, а при смене z-index не обрезает. Тому, кто был бы готов ответить на Ваш вопрос, хотелось бы иметь дело с конкретным кодом, а не предположением по тому, как это реализовано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С прозрачностью не получилось, но думаю можно так

```css
#ramka {   
    width: 80%;
    border: 10px solid rgb(19,74,136);
    border-left:0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    height: 175px;
    left: 70px;
    z-index: -1;                
}

#ramka::before {
content: "";
border-left:10px solid rgb(19,74,136);
height:20px;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
}

#ramka::after {
content: "";
border-left:10px solid rgb(19,74,136);
height:20px;
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="ramka">

</div>
```

Comment: Да :) Уже догадался сам, сейчас как раз ответ писал, но Вы меня опередили